# Using .csv file to create objects Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, csv

I am mapping my university and they provide a .csv file with a list of all of the buildings on campus. Which includes information like Building #, Name, Code, Street address, Street coordinate ect.

I want to read the values from this file to create a `NSArray` of `Building` objects.
This is how the file is formatted, how would I go about doing this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the csv into a `NSString`.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename"
                                                 ofType:@"csv"];

NSStringEncoding encoding = 0;
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *csvString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                            usedEncoding:&encoding
                                                   error:&error];
```

Parse it with your preferred method, I use an open source library, `CHCSVParser` https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser

```
NSArray *fields = [csvString CSVComponents]; // you need to import "CHCSVParser.h"
```